# Return deleted git submodule

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Hi I delete submodule which I didn't have access after some commits I found then I need that submodule back because other use it but currently it's private and I can't add using add submodule how to return deleted git submodule?

Answer (score 2):

how did you remove the submodules?

If you removed it via removing if from your `.gitmodules` file or from `.git/config`, then you just need to undo it. The data/code from the submodule will still be there locally.

However if you've removed from your disk and the project has been made private, then there's very little you can do. Perhaps there's a fork of the repo or one of your co-workers/friends has the copy of the submodule than you can reuse.

Comment: I removed from .gitmodule and also lose hash of commit

Comment: In that case, try to follow the advise in the last para or speak with the folks who made the pkg private (in case they can give access)